# combine fade and slide ( left/top/bottom/right ) with AngularJS

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I see a lot of single page app(s) that uses `fade-in` and `slide-up` during scrolling etc ..

But I can't seem to find anything that I can integrate only with Angular's `ngAnimate`, in all websites it's either install their new code with new lib and I want to stop myself from keep installing 1000 modules that at some point I can't scale ( because I don't know how to combine two animation at once )

I've seen this code example: http://codepen.io/astrotim/pen/KDBbe
And I was trying to import it and adjust it to be used with AngularJS but w/o any luck :/

### HTML

```
<div ng-if="front_wallpaper" class="animated fade-and-slide"> MyText </div>
```

### Angular's app JS

```
angular.module('app', ['ngAnimate'])
.controller('SomeCtrl', function ($scope, $timeout) {
    $scope.front_wallpaper = false;
    $timeout(function () {
        $scope.front_wallpaper = true;
    },1000);

});
```

### CSS

```
div {
            font-size: 48pt; 
            color: white; 
            position: relative; 
            left: -60%; top: 20%;
            opacity: 0;
            transition: all .75s ease;
            transition-duration: 5s;
        }

.fade-and-slide.ng-enter {  
  top: 21%;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Animation example: http://shapebootstrap.net/item/1524946-lucid-html5-and-bootstrap-responsive-template/live-demo

Or the white buttons here: http://wrapbootstrap.com/preview/WB0F82581

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Just found the answer, if we're using `animation` ( not `transition` ) we can define several animations with a comma delimiter, i.e: `openSpace` & `moveIn`

```
  -webkit-animation:
    openSpace 2s ease forwards,
    moveIn 0.3s 0.2s ease forwards;
```

Full example

```
.list-item.ng-enter {
  max-height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateX(100%);

  -webkit-animation:
    openSpace 2s ease forwards,
    moveIn 0.3s 0.2s ease forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes openSpace {
  to {
    max-height: 300px;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes moveIn {
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}
```